# Show Hide Dynamically Added Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implement search on table and it works fine. But there is one problem after I update the table row.  Search always show the edited row even if it does not match the search.

eg. steps - 
1.enter "user3" in search box then result - user3
2.edit "user3"
3.enter "user1" in search box then result - user1,user3

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tbody id="list">
<tr id="o1">
    <td class="txtclass">user</td>
    <td><a>edit</a></td>        
</tr>

<tr id="o2">
    <td class="txtclass">user2</td>
    <td><a>edit</a></td>  
</tr>

<tr id="o3">
    <td class="txtclass">user3</td>
    <td><a>edit</a></td>  
</tr>

<tr id="o4">
    <td class="txtclass">user4</td>
    <td><a>edit</a></td>  
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**script**

```
// function to replace table row
// d- table row html 
function updateRow(d) 
{ 
   $("#o3").before(d).remove(); 
}
```

// search in table row list

```
$("#textsearch").change(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var li;
        list = list of table rows;
        len = list.length;        
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            li = list[i];
            txt = $(li).find(".txtclass").text();            
            if ((txt || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0) {
                if (li.style.display == "none") { li.style.display = "block"; }
            } else {
                if (li.style.display != "none") { li.style.display = "none"; }
            }
        }        
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It seams that you keep old DOM nodes in `lis` array so if you remove the DOM using `remove()` you still have old DOM node in that array.

Comment: May you create a fiddle so as we can figure out more precisely where the problem can be located ?

Comment: If you're caching the list of rows you'll need to update the cache whenever a change is made, or pull a fresh list every time (`$("#list > li")`)

Comment: thanks for your comments it's helpful to me. Refreshing list of rows in updateRow() after remove(), it works.